# Render value different than form value with material-ui form components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I have a custom component (that I use with redux-form) that's based off Material-UI's TextField component.

How can I have it render a value different than its actual value?

Aka, if the value is negative, then have it render as `Math.abs(num)`, but still have the actual value of it be negative?

```
export const renderModTextField = ({input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom}) => (
    <TextField
        error={touched && error}
        {...input}
        {...custom}
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">{input.value >= 0 ? "+" : "-"}</InputAdornment>,
        }}
    />
);
```

Comment: You can use any JS expression in JXS, so use it. I can't see your real problem according to your example.

Comment: @devserkan It's mostly I don't know where I would override the rendered value in material-ui's TextField.

Comment: Then, I misunderstood you. Sorry for the interruption.